# Install/update EF code first migrations database through Wix

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wix, entity-framework-migrations

I´ve got an application that uses a database defined through EF code first migrations in a separate assembly. Is there any best practice for installing and furthermore upgrading the database through Wix?

As of now, I include the migrate.exe executable along with all other application components. During installation I run the executable with custom cmd parameters by a Wix custom action.